# best way for searching in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using `getServerSideProps` and function which returns JSX. I am using prisma with postgres. Currently I am using router.push with query for searching. Router method is little bit of time consuming. I am wondering is there any better way for searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getServerSideProps for Server Side generated pages, is probably good for crawlers only, since SSR takes time to load.

I would recommend 2 ways to search.

**(1)** You can continue to use getServerSideProps to return search result props for users who access your `domain/search?query=string` directly, and provide the page with the initial props. Crawlers can also crawl this page should you have backlink to the search results.

**(2)** On the front end, for users who have already loaded your page, you should make use of your /api/ endpoint (or create a /api/), to return results via `fetch` instead of reloading your entire page via `router.push`